# .NET URL rewrite with query parameters

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I need to rewrite some url from an old php project to a new .NET project. I tried to put rewrite rules in my webconfig, but with no success. What I'm doing wrong?

Specifically I need to rewrite an url like /index.php?id_product=7243&controller=product to RedirectProduct?src=7243

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SimpleURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.php$"/>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id_product=(.*)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/RedirectProduct?src={C:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to get detailed error information. If you still can't solve it, please post the complete url and I will make a demo for you as a reference.